# How to allocate memory using a pointer to pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am trying to understand code snippets in 
[free a double pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015360/free-a-double-pointer)

and
[Why use double pointer? or Why use pointers to pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580761/why-use-double-pointer-or-why-use-pointers-to-pointers)

I want to understand the difference between the following. Both snippets are from the above urls

```
int** pt; 

pt = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

and

```
*pt = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

Could you elaborate with some examples and drawing

Comment: Please don’t refer to a pointer-to-pointer as a “double pointer”. The latter sounds far too much like a pointer-to-double, which is a completely different animal.

Comment: Don't use malloc in C++.

Comment: @PeteBecker Fixed. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @manni66. I am using C not C++. I am looking for an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use double pointer? or Why use pointers to pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580761/why-use-double-pointer-or-why-use-pointers-to-pointers)

Comment: @user2979872, the short answer is when (1) you need to point to objects of differing size, or (2) objects that are non-contiguous in memory. Otherwise, a pointer itself and pointer arithmetic would suffice.

Comment: shame on -ve reppers, who give no valid explanation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, the code snippet is bad for several reasons - the first is casting the result of `malloc` to the wrong type, and is using the wrong type to compute the amount of memory.  Fixing the cast and type issues, we have:

```
int **pt;

 pt = malloc( sizeof  *pt * 10 );   // allocate space for 10 int *
*pt = malloc( sizeof **pt * 10 );   // allocate space for 10 int
```

After executing the first line, you have the following:

```
     int **                int *
    +---+                 +---+
pt: |   | --------------->|   | pt[0]
    +---+                 +---+       
                          |   | pt[1]
                          +---+
                          |   | pt[2]
                          +---+
                           ...
                          +---+
                          |   | pt[9]
                          +---+
```

You've set aside space for 10 `int *` objects, and `pt` points to the first of them.

The next line

```
*pt = malloc( sizeof **pt * 10 ); // allocate space for 10 int
```

allocates space for 10 `int` objects, and sets `pt[0]` to point to them:

```
     int **                int *                int 
    +---+                 +---+                +---+
pt: |   | --------------->|   | pt[0] -------->|   | pt[0][0]
    +---+                 +---+                +---+
                          |   | pt[1]          |   | pt[0][1]
                          +---+                +---+
                          |   | pt[2]          |   | pt[0][2]
                          +---+                +---+
                           ...                  ...
                          +---+                +---+
                          |   | pt[9]          |   | pt[0][9]
                          +---+                +---+
```

This illustrates one way of allocating a "jagged" array; you can still index it as `pt[i][j]`, but unlike a true 2D array the rows are not adjacent in memory, and each row may be a different length.  You'd normally write that as

```
pt = malloc( sizeof *pt * ROWS );
if ( pt )
{
  for ( size_t r = 0; r < ROWS; r++ )
  {
    pt[r] = malloc( sizeof *pt[r] * COLS );
  }
}
```

When that's all done, you have something like this:

```
     int **           int *                 int
    +---+            +---+                 +---+---+     +---+
pt: |   | ---------> |   | pt[0] --------> |   |   | ... |   | pt[0][0] - pt[0][COLS-1]
    +---+            +---+                 +---+---+     +---+
                     |   | pt[1] ------+
                     +---+             |   +---+---+     +---+
                     |   | pt[2] ---+  +-> |   |   | ... |   | pt[1][0] - pt[1][COLS-1]
                     +---+          |      +---+---+     +---+
                      ...           | 
                                    |      +---+---+     +---+
                                    +----> |   |   | ... |   | pt[2][0] - pt[2][COLS-1]
                                           +---+---+     +---+
```

Comment: The casting of the result is a very good idea because it allows the compiler to issue a message for this statement pt = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*10);

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: using `sizeof *pt` instead of `sizeof(int)` eliminates that particular issue.  `T *p = malloc( sizeof *p * N );` will always do the right thing, regardless of `T`.

Comment: Are you sure? Consider for example char *p = malloc( sizeof( struct A ) ); and char *p = malloc( sizeof *p );

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I'm not sure what point you're trying to make - if my target is `p`, I'm going to use `sizeof *p`, not `sizeof some_arbitrary_type_that_isn't_the_same_type_as_*p`.

Comment: It is not always is true. For example you need to allocate a character buffer that to copy a structure or you need to allocate a one-dimensional array that can accommodate a two-dimensional array and so on.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Then the size of the structure or the array would be my `N`: `struct A instance; char *p = malloc( sizeof *p * sizeof instance ); if (p) memcpy( p, &instance, sizeof instance);`, etc.

Comment: It can be that in the moment of executing this statement  char *p = malloc( sizeof *p * sizeof instance );  there is no any instance. Moreover this statement is awful for readers. Take into account that it is not necessary that the call of malloc is used in a declaration. So nobody knows what type of p.

Answer (score 3):

The following is wrong, compiler should complain about types:

```
int** pt;     
pt = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

This is also wrong for another reason (here `pt` does not actually point to anything usable):

```
int** pt;     
*pt = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

A pointer to `T` is a variable of type `T *` that may contain address of some memory that may contains elements of type `T`:

```
+------+
|      | pointer to T 
+------+
    |
    v
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|             |             |             | elements of type T
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

For example, in C, to obtain what is drawn, you can write:

```
int *pi;
pi = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
```

If you have a pointer to pointer to `T` then then diagram could be something like:

```
+------+
|      | pointer to pointer to T 
+------+
    |
    v
+------+------+------+
|      |      |      | pointers to T 
+------+------+------+
    |      |      |     +-------------+-------------+-------------+
    |      |      +---->|             |             |             | elements of type T
    |      |            +-------------+-------------+-------------+ 
    |      |     +-------------+-------------+
    |      +---->|             |             | elements of type T
    |            +-------------+-------------+ 
    |
    v
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|             |             |             |             | elements of type T
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

and the code could be:

```
int **ppi;
ppi = malloc(sizeof(int *)*3);
ppi[0] = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
ppi[1] = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
ppi[2] = malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
```

Of course, `malloc` could fail and return value should be tested against failure.

Answer (score 0):

Using the casting you helped the compiler to find an error in this code snippet

```
int** pt; 

pt = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

For example the error message can look like

```
 error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  pt = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
     ^
```

Without the casting the compiler could accept this evidently invalid code because the return type of the function `malloc` is `void *` and a pointer of  the type `void *` may be assigned to a pointer to object of any other type.

That is in the right side of the assignment the evaluated expression has the type `int *` while in the left side of the assignment there is an object of the type `int **` and there is no implicit conversion from the type `int *` to the type `int **`.

This code snippet

```
int** pt; 

*pt = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

is invalid by another reason. The pointer `pt` is not initialized by a valid address of an object.  It has either indeterminate value if the pointer has automatic storage duration or NULL if the pointer has static storage duration. In any case its dereferencing results in undefined behavior.

So it would be correctly to write

```
int* pt; 
^^^^^^^
pt = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

However this construction

```
int** pt; 

//...

*pt = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

can be made valid in some context.

Let's assume that you declared a pointer

```
int *pt;
```

and want to initialize it in a function. In this case you have to pass the pointer to the function by reference. Otherwise the function will deal with a copy of the pointer and in this case the original pointer will not be assigned in the function.

So the corresponding code snippet can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

size_t f( int **pt )
{
    const size_t N = 10;

    *pt = (int*) malloc( sizeof( int ) * N );

    if ( *pt )
    {
        int value = 0;
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) ( *pt )[i] = value++;
    }

    return *pt == NULL ? 0 : N;
}

int main( void )
{
    int *pt;

    size_t n = f( &pt );

    if ( n )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", pt[i] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    free( pt );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: can't you pass pointer to f ( ) like f(pt) from main (). If not , why not?

Comment: @user2979872 In fact I described why it is impossible in my answer. Can you elaborate what exactly is unclear?

Comment: the thing that is not clear is the difference between f(pt) and f(&pt). As you declared pt as int *pt, I am wondering what is the difference between pt and &pt. If i understood correctly, &pt means the address of pt and pt points to the address of pointee (only when assigned like pt = &a where a is declared as int a = 5). Otherwise pt points to no valid address. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @user2979872 pt and &pt are different types and this is written in the answer. So the compiler will issue an error because the type of the argument does not correspond to the type of the parameter. We are going to change the original pt in the function. So we have to pass it by reference otherwise the function will deal with a copy of the pt and the copy (not the original pt) will be change in the function.

Comment: @user2979872 I am sorry but I do not understand what you mean in the comment. The expression &pt yields the address of the variable pt itself. A pointer is an object as any other objects. So you can apply operator & to get its address.

Comment: First thank you for your patience. All i am trying to understand is the difference between &pt and pt itself without any * or &